# dompdf, firefox hangs on PDF generation

Tags: pdf, firefox, dompdf

I have a dompdf installation that generates PDF datasheets. This is web server hosted, not local. The system works with Safari and Chrome on Mac and Internet Explorer on PC. However, the PDF generation hangs when using Firefox on Mac. I am assuming this is a Firefox issue as testing the live version online and also using a local installation using MAMP Pro produces the same problem.

Any feedback would be gratefully received.